# issues when raising dataframe to the power of -0.5 - R

Tags: r

I am trying raise a `data.frame` to the power of -0.5. Can someone please tell me why this will not work?

```
 x <- c(-1,-5,-6) #minus data
 x^-0.5           #raisin'
[1] NaN NaN NaN   

 -69508.00^-0.5   #checking that i'm not being a moron
[1] -0.003792998

 -5^-0.5          #double-checking that i'm not being a moron
[1] -0.4472136

 x2 <- c(10, 20, 30) #positive data
 x2^-0.5             #raisin'
[1] 0.3162278 0.2236068 0.1825742
```

Comment: The issue is that the square root of a negative number is imaginary, so R returns a missing value. `-69508.00^-0.5` is evaluated as `-(69508.00)^(-0.5)` so it performs the square root first then the subtraction, but the other numbers are evaluated as negative first.

Comment: But why does it work when not in dataframe?

Comment: @squishy, its a vector in this case, not a data.frame

Comment: Because it evaluates it as `0-(69508^-0.5)`.

Comment: @SamDickson @.mkemp6  thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your double checking is just order of operations at work. R will not return the square root of a negative number since it is imaginary:

```
> (-69508.00)^(-0.5)
[1] NaN
> -(69508.00)^(-0.5)
[1] -0.003792998
```

Comment: ...unless, of course, `as.complex(-69508.00)^(-0.5)`.